# log4net , handling Windows Azure SQL Database Connection String

Tags: logging, azure-sql-database, log4net

```
  Having a web.config connection for log4net and works fine ( without tcp/ port etc ) 
  Now Using connection details from Windows Azure SQL Database (formerly SQL Azure) Connection String
```

web.config
      Eg: Data Source=tcp:AXXXXXX03,1433;Initial Catalog=CXXUserDB;User ID=CXXUserID;Password=CXXUserPassword;Persist Security Info=False;

```
  When I running the application  getting the below error ( captured  using Diagnostics property ) 
  ERROR [AdoNetAppender] ErrorCode: GenericFailure. Exception while writing to database
  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The INSERT permission was denied on the object 'MyTable'
  MyTable having identity and index also defined 

 Question , What are the changes we have to do when we use Azure Connection String instead of our old connection in web.config. ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide permissions to INSERT on that database to the database user. Use SQL Server Management Studio to run the following statements on the user database.

```
-- Run this on the user database not on master database 
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datawriter',  'CXXUserID'
```

You can also assign it read permission on the database.

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader',  'CXXUserID'
```

Comment: Tried with that Alberto , but in my case no luck . When the configuration doesnt use connectiongstring from Azure , it works. Thanks for your kind response

Comment: I have executed  EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader',  'CXXUserID' , for some reason I have to remove my user role - EXEC sp_droprolemember  , its executed but still log4net is putting the logs . How I can STOP

Answer (score 1):

```
Created a table with clustered index and given permission 

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datawriter',  'CXXUserID'
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader',  'CXXUserID'



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Log4Net] 
(
[Id] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Thread] [varchar] (255) NOT NULL,
[Level] [varchar] (50) NOT NULL,
[Logger] [varchar] (255) NOT NULL,
[Message] [varchar] (4000) NOT NULL,
[Exception] [varchar] (2000) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_MyLog] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
)
 few more information available : https://blog.tallan.com/2017/07/18/log-management-with-log4net-and-microsoft-azure/
```

Comment: Giving permission for Sys_stored procedure wont be possible in 
     Production database .